# Universe polymorphism: the inference of universes and their constraints

Tags: type-theory, coq, type-inference, calculus-of-constructions, polymorphism

When making a universe polymorphic definition in Coq, universes and their constraints are automatically inferred. Are they somewhat the most general ones (in a sense similar to the principal type property in ML)? Or are they just the result of arbitrary heuristics? Or something in between?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's complicated because universe constraints are simplified during inference (in order to avoid an explosion of constraints). Have a look at:

- Matthieu Sozeau and Nicolas Tabareau: [Universe Polymorphism in Coq](https://www.irif.fr/~sozeau/research/publications/Universe_Polymorphism_in_Coq.pdf), Interactive Theorem Proving - 5th International Conference, ITP 2014
- Beta Ziliani & Matthieu Sozeau: [A Unification Algorithm for Coq featuring Universe Polymorphism and Overloading](https://www.irif.fr/~sozeau/research/publications/A_Unification_Algorithm_for_Coq_featuring_Universe_Polymorphism_and_Overloading-ICFP15.pdf), ACM SIGPLAN International Conference on Functional Programming 2015.

Comment: What if those simplifications are omitted?

Comment: Then you get a combinatorial explosion and your computer releases [blue smoke](http://www.jargon.net/jargonfile/m/magicsmoke.html). Also, if the downvoter would care to explain the downvote, I could improve the answer. I know it's terse, but this really is not the place for a general introduction on how universe constraints are handled.

Comment: Assuming I have a very good ventilation and that I omit the simplifications, will a distant descendant of mine get the most general universe and constraint assignment?

Comment: I am not entirely sure but I think there isn’t always the most general form of universe polymorphism. And even if there is one, that doesn’t mean it’s a useful thing to have. For instance the most general form may not tell you whether it’s consistent. You’d just get a bunch of constraints and it’s up to you to tell whether they’re consistent.

Comment: You might also want to mention "Type Checking with Universes" by Harper and Pollack; this is what Coq's algorithm is based on.

Comment: According to https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/3-540-50940-2_39 "We show type synthesis is effective in CCω. Even if explicit universe levels are erased from a term it is possible to compute a “schematic type” for that term, and a set of constraints, that characterize all types of all well-typed instances of the term. "  So I suspect there is in fact a "most general" set of universes and constraints, or perhaps multiple equivalent sets.

Comment: I thought the current Coq universe polymorphisms algorithm is an extension of Harper & Pollack's algorithm. Since it uses fairly general constraints, I hesitate to just conclude there is a good notion of "most general".